# Listagg Equivalent in Power Query - M

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, listagg

Using PowerQuery, ideally M, I want my table to go from:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below, assuming data is loaded into range Table1

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
New= Table.Group( Source, {"Student_ID"}, {{"Subjects_Taken", each Text.Combine([Subjects_Taken], ", "), type text}})
in New
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. My data is not in Excel. It is already loaded into PowerQuery via the data warehouse. Do you know how I would modify your script above?

Comment: This is powerquery code, as viewed with file... advanced editor....  within power query .  View your code, add the second row, replacing Source with the name of your prior step